# What did Feynman say about cesium chloride and body-centered cubic structure?

Tags: crystals, x-ray-crystallography

The slideshare.net slides [Basic crystallography](https://www.slideshare.net/MukhlisAdam/basic-crystallography) shows an illustration of (what looks like) the interleaved nature of the cesium and chlorine cubic arrangements in a CsCl crystal. The text on the slides

> Monatomic Body-Centred Cubic (BCC) crystal Lattice: bcc CsCl crystal Lattice: simple cubic BCC Feynman! Corner and body-centres have the same neighbourhood Corner and body-centred atoms do not have the same neighbourhood Motif: 1 atom 000 Motif: two atoms Cl 000; Cs ½ ½ ½ Cs Cl

includes a red line through BCC appearing to cross it out, then the name *Feynman!* in red with a box around it.

**Question:** Did Richard Feynman say or write anything in particular about this?

[image]

related: [Cesium chloride crystal structure](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/456258/83380)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Google search turned up the May 2016 IAS article [Errors in The Feynman Lectures on Physics; Symmetry and Crystals](https://www.ias.ac.in/article/fulltext/reso/021/05/0429-0437) by Rajesh Prasad, which I think explains the remark. In Vol. II, Section 30.4 of the FLP, Feynman claims that

> The dark and light spheres in the drawings may, in general, stand for different kinds of atoms or may be the same kind.

in reference to this figure, which is meant to show a bcc structure:

[image]

However, if the light sphere is different from the dark, then the crystal structure is of [CsCl/B2 type](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/michael.leitner/lattice/struk/b2.html) rather than [bcc/A2](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/michael.leitner/lattice/struk/a2.html).

Comment: Your link is particularly interesting and helpful, e.g. trigonal vs hexagonal, bilateral symmetry vs. two-fold axis, etc... Thanks for the speedy answer!